# ms word-2003 Search and Replace text

Tags: python, ms-word

how to find and replace text in ms word 2003  using python ?
I want to search a word in a table and paragraphs as well.

Thank You !

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1f367bx.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-9

How to implement this in Python ?

Comment: I want to write a story in ms word 2003 using python.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def fetchpnum(self,searchable):
        # print self.doc1.Paragraphs.Count
        for i in range(1, self.doc1.Paragraphs.Count):
            value = self.doc1.Paragraphs(i).Range.Text.lower()
            if value.startswith(searchable.lower()):
                return i
        return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can refer this link  [How to read contents of an Table in MS-Word file Using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366596/reading-table-contetnts-in-ms-word-file-using-python)

You can access the table contents with particular row and column.

Comment: Thanks for help,But i need to know hot to find a particular text in a column and replace it.

Comment: http://virantha.com/2013/08/16/reading-and-writing-microsoft-word-docx-files-with-python/ here you go...