# Writing a pandas dataframe to a word document table via pywin32

Tags: python, pandas, ms-word, python-3.4, pywin32

I am currently working on a script that needs to write to a .docx file for presentation purposes.  I use pandas to handle all my data calculations in the script.  I am looking to write a pandas dataframe into a table at a bookmark in a word.docx file using PyWIN32. The dataframe consists of floats. The psuedo code is something like this.

```
frame = DataFrame(np.arange(28).reshape((4,7)), columns=['Text1',...'Text7'])
```

With pywin32 imported...

```
wordApp = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')
wordApp.Visible = False
doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(os.getcwd()+'\\template.docx')
rng = doc.Bookmarks("PUTTABLEHERE").Range
rng.InsertTable.here
```

Now i would like to create a table at this bookmark.  The dimensions of the table should be dictated by the dataframe. I would also like the column titles to be the header in the Word table.

Comment: While this isn't really a direct answer to your question, you may want to consider exporting to an Excel spreadsheet (pandas DataFrames have a [to_excel()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) function) and inserting the resulting table into your document.

Comment: You may not be able to automate the whole process (I'm totally unfamiliar with PyWin32), but that's sort of the expense of using Windows and GUI applications.

Comment: Worth noticing when working with pywin32 is that in many cases it won't let you load more than 2GB of data into memory, which is sometimes a problem when using pandas. This is because it's a 32bit process in windows and these kind of processes are often limited to 2GB by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, all you need to do is create a table in word and populate the values of each cell from the corresponding values of data frame

```
# data frame
df= DataFrame(np.arange(28).reshape((4,7)), columns=['Text1',...'Text7'])

wordApp = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')
wordApp.Visible = False
doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(os.getcwd()+'\\template.docx')
rng = doc.Bookmarks("PUTTABLEHERE").Range

# creating Table 
# add one more row in table at word because you want to add column names as header
Table=rng.Tables.Add(rng,NumRows=df.shape[0]+1,NumColumns=df.shape[1])

for col in range(df.shape[1]):        
    # Writing column names 
    Table.Cell(1,col+1).Range.Text=str(df.columns[col]) 
    for row in range(df.shape[0]):
        # writing each value of data frame 
        Table.Cell(row+1+1,col+1).Range.Text=str(df.iloc[row,col])
```

Notice that `Table.Cell(row+1+1,col+1)` has been added two ones here. The reason is because Table in Microsoft Word start indexing from 1. So, both row and col has to be added 1 because data frame indexing in pandas start from 0.

Another 1 is added at row to give space for data frame columns as headers. That should do it !