# How to get specific table from Word Doc using win32 COM?

Tags: python, ms-word, win32com, python-docx

I am attempting to go through a word document and find a few specific tables among many tables. I know how to iterate through all tables using either the docx library or win32, found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366596/how-to-read-contents-of-an-table-in-ms-word-file-using-python). However, I need to access a few specific tables, not all of them.

These tables have headings, in the format of `Table A.x.x-x Insert table summary`. They are text headings above the tables, not within the tables themselves. These don't show up when I use `doc.ListParagraphs` from win32, however, so I can't successfully iterate through the tables in that manner.

I know the name of the table I need to access. There is unrelated text throughout the document. There aren't any blanket similarities in the tables I need to find, so I can't just look for a specific value in a certain cell or something like that.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to approach this? Preferably using win32 COM, but I'm open to any solutions.

Comment: Are the headings part of the actual table or are they "heading" paragraphs separate from the table?

Comment: They are heading paragraphs separate from the table, directly above it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out an answer, using [this](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/40) discussion. Thanks for the clarification on which win32 COM function to use!

From the discussion, I used the code for iter_block_items. I also made a list of all the table titles of the titles that I wanted, called listOfTables. I then used the following code, which outputs a dictionary, the keys being the title of the tables and the values being the tables themselves.

`dox = docx.Document(path)
    count = False
    tables = {}
    for item in iter_block_items(dox):
        try:
            title = item.text
            if title in listOfTables:
                count = True
        except:
            if count == True:
                tables[str(title)] = item
                count = False
    print tables`

If it comes upon a table, we go to the except case because a table has no attribute 'text'. Then, if count is true, aka if the previous paragraph contained a table title, then store the title and the table itself in a dictionary. This will pair the titles with the appropriate tables, and I'll have easy access to the table I need.

Answer (score 0):

I think the collection you're looking for is `doc.Paragraphs`.

`doc.ListParagraphs` only returns paragraphs that have list formatting, like bullets or numbers.

There are other challenges involved, but that's the first mystery solved I believe :)