# Iterating through cell sentences/paragraphs - docx tables

Tags: python, docx, pywin32

I am looking to iterate through sentences/paragraphs within cells of a docx table, performing functions depending on their style tags using the pywin32 module.

I can manually select the cell using
`cell = table.Cell(Row = 1, Column =2)`

I tried using something like 
`for x in cell:` 
`#do something`
 but
  `<class 'win32com.client.CDispatch'>` objects 'do not support enumeration'

I tried looking through: [Word OM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/word/object-model) to find a solution but to no avail (I understand this is for VBA, but still can be very useful)

Comment: Does [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366596/how-to-read-contents-of-an-table-in-ms-word-file-using-python) answer your question?

Comment: Its works yes. The problem I am having is words are being printed character by character. How can I print them word by word?
```for word in table.Cell(Row =2, Column =2).Range.Text:
    print(word)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example that reads the content from the the first row / first column of the first table in a document and prints it word-by-word:

```
import win32com.client as win32
import os

wordApp = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Word.Application")
wordApp.Visible = False
doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(os.getcwd() + "\\Test.docx")
table = doc.Tables(1)
for word in table.Cell(Row = 1, Column = 1).Range.Text.split():
    print(word)
wordApp.Application.Quit(-1)
```

The cell's content is just a string, you could easily also split it by paragraphs using `split('\r')` or by sentences using `split('.')`.

Comment: Thanks @Gerd. Is a manual iteration the only the way to cycle through the cells? e.g. ```(Row = counter, Column = counter1).Range.Text.split():```

Comment: @TheMob: Yes, this is what I would do. Number of rows and columns can be determined by `table.Rows.Count` and `table.Columns.Count`.