# Unable to write a code to read table from word document in python

Tags: python

I am a newbie and I started learning Python on my own by seeing videos. I have a task to read table from word document using python and populate it to database.

I can able to write the code to read the paragraphs by using the below code. Can anyone please guide me how to write the code for reading the table form word document? Thanks

```
import docx
doc = docx.Document('Text.docx')
doc.paragraphs
doc.paragraphs[0].text
doc.paragraphs[1].text
```

Samlpe table:

Heading
Name1   Desc1
Desc1   Desc2
Name3   Desc3
Name4   Desc4
Desc1   Desc5
Name6   Desc6
Name7   Desc7

I tried writing code to read paragraphs but I am searching how to write the code to read the table

Answer (score 0):

You can use the docx library:

```
from docx import Document

doc = Document('Text.docx')

for table in doc.tables:
    for row in table.rows:
        for cell in row.cells:
            print cell.text
```

Similar question can be found here: [How to read contents of an Table in MS-Word file Using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366596/how-to-read-contents-of-an-table-in-ms-word-file-using-python)